# Required and not required fields from one common class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and I have the following class:

```
public class AddressMetadata
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have the following edit model:

```
[Display(Name = "First Address")]
public Address FirstAddress { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Second Address")]
public Address SecondAddress { get; set; }
```

And I have to create all fields from FirstAddress as required, but the other ones from SecondAddress not.

How can I do that without creating new class for second address? I know that I can use **[Required]** directive in AddressMetadata class, but how can I divide those rules between FirstAddress and SecondAddress?

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this will work, not 100% sure, I've to try it myself. (I'm actually starting with EditorTemplates)

- Add [Required] just to FirstAddress in the EditModel.
- Add [Required] to all properties of the Adress class.
- Write a TemplateEditor for Address class.

The TemplateEditor will have Address as its model and perform validation on that using Address class annotations, while the View will validate according to the EditModel annotations.

Please forgive me for my bad English.

EDIT: was forgetting about this: in the view render the EditorTemplate via

```
@Html.EditorFor (m => m.FirstAddress)
```